# Eclipse SVN commit direct change to tomcat remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tomcat

I have develop web application using **spring and hibernate without maven** for managing sub-version i am using SVN all those things working well.
Now my problem is that when i done a little changes in my application then create war file and deploy using tomcat manager and it is more time consuming process for me to perform all those task for a small changes.

Can i do like this when i **commit using svn(or any other sub-version tools like git) then direct changes to my application which is running on tomcat remove server**.

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try to use an SVN Hook. Anyway I would not advice on that, for the possibility of doing partial commits. The obvious alternative is an OSB, with the tool of your choice (I prefer Ant).

Comment: OSB is plugin for eclipse?

Comment: OSB is One Step Build, it is a process that performs all of the steps you desire. Usually a makefile or ant script.

Comment: i can not find any thinks about OSB  so please if you have any doc link this share with me. because when i try to search about OSB then can not find any appropriate result according to my requirements.